# How to use the result of a function as a parameter in a loop?

Tags: c#, function, for-loop, parameter-passing

Using C#, I want to loop through a method with the result of the first iteration being used as a parameter for the next.

Ex:

```
public int function(int x)
{

y = x + 1;

return y;

}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

//I want to use the result of this function as the next parameter in the loop//

int z = function(1);

}
```

Comment: I don't follow what you mean.

Comment: Besides the fact that `function` returns exactly what you put in (and not `y`), are you saying that you want the previous loop's `z` value for the next loop?

Comment: so basically first iteration would be z =2, the second would be z = 3, and so on....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Declare `z` before your loop. You will need to give it some default value - the value you want to use for the first loop.

Then use `z` within the loop. Until you reassign the variable, it will be the last loop's value.

```
int z = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    z = function(z);
}
```